# Alexandria/Silverlight 3 features list?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Is there a resource out there which lists the features, functionality and potential release date of Silverlight 3 (currently called Alexandria)?

My group is currently building a product with Silverlight 2 as the deployment platform.
We need to research/be prepared for Alexandria, and see if it will resolve some of our issues.

Comment: SL 3 is still under NDA. 

This <a href="http://209.85.173.132/search?q=cache:4NNB9vlulqcJ:channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC11/+jAMES+COOL+PRESENTATION+MIX+SILVERLIGHT&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=4">presentation</a> may help you some.

I would expect MS to release (beta?) something during MIX09.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/16/update-on-silverlight-2-and-a-glimpse-of-silverlight-3.aspx) is your all-knowing source of all things Silverlight.  As far as I've seen that posting is the latest and most authoritative information on SL3.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the major/cool features are expected to be announced at Mix next week.

Channel 9 has video that lists some features at: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/The+Knowledge+Chamber/Brad-Abrams-Silverlight-30-for-Great-Business-Apps/

There are some neat features including
New Web Navigation project type 
Support for hooking into back/forward buttons and deep linking
Detail control 
Enhancements to data grid

They are also expected to support more video formats.

Some cool stuff coming up now if only they could improve the tools to work with it!

Answer (score 0):

Alexandria is actually not the codename for Silverlight 3. It is a codename for some technology leveraged by Silverlight 3, but not Silverlight 3 itself.

Here are some important sessions:

**What’s New in Silverlight 3**

A summary of all new features in Silverlight 3.

http://sessions.visitmix.com/MIX09/T14F

**Amazing Business Centric Apps in Silverlight 3**

Covers domain services (connecting server data to Silverlight client), the data grid, paging, sorting, filtering, the data form control, validation and more.

http://sessions.visitmix.com/MIX09/T40F

**Intro to the Data Form Control**

*Not a Mix Session* but a great deep follow-up to the above session. Goes in depth on the Data Form control, related attributes, etc.

http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=187317